# Apply a function to each column of a data.frame and organize the output

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply, sapply

I have this vector:

```
 x <- c(5,2,-4,-6,-2,1,4,2,-3,-6,-1,8,9,5,-6,-11)
```

I use this function:

```
myfunction <- function(x){
     n <- length(x)
     fx <- numeric(n)
     fx[1] <- min(x[1],0)
     for(i in 2:n){fx[i] <- min(0,fx[i-1]+x[i])}
     fx

     x_min <-min(x)
     fx_min <- min(fx)

     fx_05 <- numeric(n)
     fx_05[1] <- min(fx[1],0)
     for (i in 2:n) {
       if (sum(fx_05[i-1]+x[i])>0) {  
          fx_05[i] <- 0
       } else if ((sum(fx_05[i-1]+x[i]))<(fx_min*0.5)) {
          fx_05[i] <- (fx_min*0.5)
       } else { fx_05[i] <- sum(fx_05[i-1]+x[i]) }
     }
     fx_05
     as.data.frame(matrix(c(x, fx_05), ncol = 2 ))
}
xx <- myfunction(x)
```

The dataframe `xx` is

```
    V1   V2
1    5  0.0
2    2  0.0
3   -4 -4.0
4   -6 -8.5
5   -2 -8.s
6    1 -7.5
7    4 -3.5
8    2 -1.5
9   -3 -4.5
10  -6 -8.5
11  -1 -8.5
12   8 -0.5
13   9  0.0
14   5  0.0
15  -6 -6.0
16 -11 -8.5`
```

I would like to apply this function to a data.frame :

```
df <- data.frame(x <- c(5,2,-4,-6,-2,1,4,2,-3,-6,-1,8,9,5,-6,-11),
                   y <- c(5,2,-4,-6,-2,1,4,2,-3,-6,-1,8,9,5,-6,-11),
                   z <- c(5,2,-4,-6,-2,1,4,2,-3,-6,-1,8,9,5,-6,-11))
```

Using:

```
output <- myfunction(df)
```

It doesn't work, and using:

```
outputs <- data.frame(sapply(df, myfunction))
```

the form of the data.frame output is not correct. It should be 2 columns for each original column of the data.frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you would like to use `lapply`. It will handle each column of the data.frame, as it actually is a list of equal-length vectors, and return a two column data.frame each.

```
x <- lapply(df, myfunction)
```

Also, `sapply` works just fine. The only difference is that it looks different at the beginning. See `print(x)` for the difference between all solutions.

```
x <- sapply(df, myfunction)
```

Afterwards you probably want to combine them from a list to a data.frame again. You can do this with `do.call`

```
df2 <- do.call(cbind, x)
```

This will mess up the column names. You can change these using `names`

```
names(df2) <- NULL
df2
# 1    5  0.0   5  0.0   5  0.0
# 2    2  0.0   2  0.0   2  0.0
# 3   -4 -4.0  -4 -4.0  -4 -4.0
# 4   -6 -8.5  -6 -8.5  -6 -8.5
# ....
```

#### Side Note:

If you don't have a data.frame but a matrix as input, another option would be `apply` with the with `MARGIN = 2`.

```
x <- apply(df, MARGIN = 2, myfunction)
```

Although in this example, it works as well, you will run into trouble when having differing data types across your vectors as it converts the data.frame to a matrix before applying the function. Therefore it is not recommended. More info on that can be found in [this detailed and easy-to-understand post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/3250126)!

Further reading on this:
[Hadley Wickham's Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html). Also check out the section on data types on this site.
[Peter Werner's blog post](https://petewerner.blogspot.com/2012/12/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r.html)

---

I greatly appreciate the input of [@Gregor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903061/gregor) on this post.

Comment: Please don't equate `lapply` and `sapply` with `apply(..., MARGIN = 2)`. `apply` is meant for matrices, and should be used when that is appropriate. I'm struggling to think of a case when `apply(df, MARGIN = 2)` is needed on a data frame, almost always `lapply` or `sapply` should be used.

Comment: I understand your concerns. Would you prefer to remove it from the answer, or mark it as one possible but inconvenient solution? I merely included it since it leads to the desired output.

Comment: If it were my answer, I'd just remove it. Nice and simple. Even better would be to move it to the bottom and explain. Something like "if you have a matrix, not a data frame, use `apply`. It's possible to use `apply` on a data frame, but it will first convert the data frame to a `matrix`, which is risky if you have columns of different types, so if you have a data frame it's probably better to just use `l/s/vapply`." But with more detail. Maybe link out to [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/903061) for more info.